# How do I prove my proxy is scanning for viruses?

Tags: proxy, antivirus

I have a proxy server in my DMZ that among other tasks has the role of scanning incoming messages - email, SOAP - for viruses. How do I prove to my team leader that it is performing this role on all incoming messages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't really prove it, without going through proxy lo gs, antivirus logs etc., but you can certainly get confidence that it is by sending some test messages through with the EICAR signatures in it (see http://www.eicar.org/anti_virus_test_file.htm).

You can then see whether it flags them.

Answer (score -1):

Logs is the most possible option. Since the server is in the DMZ, it would be rather easy. The AV will log the details of the triggered asset and the "ahost" machine thus proving that the proxy is doing what it is supposed to.